# Is there any way to check if contents of file have been changed in VB6?

Tags: vba, vb6, filesystems, filesystemwatcher

We have created a .NET application using the FileSystemWatcher Class which raises an changed event once the content of the particular file has changed.

Now, we need to implement this application in VB6. Is there any way to check if contents of file have been changed in VB6?

I have read [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4997/Spying-a-file-system) and [article2](http://www.desaware.com/tech/filemonitoring.aspx). But, it looks like they are watching all files within folder. I want to implement program that checks if contents of 1 .txt file has changed.

There is this FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE filter of ReadDirectoryChangesW API would do the trick? Even then, how do I hook it to 1 file (rather than entire directory)?

**Is there any sample code reference for this.. I have worked on .NET but am very new to VB6...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a date stamp on the file, just check that. It's a bit arbitrary when it comes to idempotent writes - if you write a 0 over a 0, does that count as a write/change? But that's usually not a problem.

Comment: Do you mean I have to save the old timestamp somewhere and check it? or is there something else on your mind?

Comment: Well, the filesystemwatcher only works while your program is running, so apparently you could just keep the old timestamp in memory.

Comment: What do you feel about this sendmessage API example:- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176058/en-us

Comment: @Nachiket: Unrelated?

Comment: Do I need to use polling to check the change every second? or is there any other way?

Comment: You'd still watch the directory for any changes, and only check the timestamp if something in the directory changed (`FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE`). At that moment, the directory data is in memory anyway so the timestamp check on that one file is quick.